# configure lan card for ASRock H510 PRO BTC+

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a machine with a ASRock H510 PRO BTC+ motherboard, but the lan card is not recognized.

This is what is listed on the spec page:

```
- Gigabit LAN 10/100/1000 Mb/s
- Giga PHY Intel® I219V
- Supports Wake-On-LAN
- Supports Lightning/ESD Protection
- Supports Energy Efficient Ethernet 802.3az
- Supports PXE
```

(from https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/H510%20Pro%20BTC+/index.la.asp#Specification)

Could anybody make this mother work with ubuntu?

---

I just changes to Ubuntu 21.10 and it recognized it right out of the box
thanks for the comments!

Comment: Any Intel Gigabit LAN chipset should be supported. How did you came to the conclusion it isn't recognized? Are you sure it isn't disabled in UEFI?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of two terminal commands: `sudo modprobe e1000e` and: `sudo dmesg | grep e100`